# Is it possible to use yasnippet and auto-complete together?

Tags: emacs

For example:

I would like to expand def to

```
def method(arg)
end
```

but auto-complete finds define_method and I can no longer expand def. Is it possible to configure either yasnippet or auto-complete to make this work ?